# Model create returns object without ID

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm doing this:

```
$item = Item::create(["name"=>"Hello"]);
dd($item->id);
```

Displays null;

Comment: Does your model contain ` protected $fillable = ['name'];` ?

Comment: I think your item model does not have `id` column.  Please check it with only print item objects like `dd($item);`

Comment: Can you show migration and model for Item?

Comment: The table has ID and some fillable fields. It's called inside a transaction. The row is actually created in the database, but after calling create the object returned doesn't contain an id field

Comment: Does your new record contain an id ? or the latter is null in the database ?

Comment: yes it has an id

Comment: As wrote @MichalOravec show us Migration or Database table structure. maybe you forgot set ID column as Autoincrement

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson Could you please share value `dd(item);`?

Comment: Is the database column named `id` or `ID`? This might make a difference depending on you OS and database.

Comment: One possibility here could be that the `id` is put under `hidden` inside your model.